# CLAVIN use for GeoCoding

Tags: geocoding

I would like to a offline package to determine the country a person lives in from a text field in a database named locatoin. I started using [CLAVIN](http://clavin.bericotechnologies.com/) which gives good results sometimes but surprisingly dosn't work on easy results. For example:

- "Toronto, Canada"
- "Fremantle, WA"

Both fail to return a result. I have deliberately skipped out the GeoParsing steps as I already know the text is an location. I am using the LuceneLocationResolver class, for example initialise the object:

```
LuceneLocationResolver locRes = new LuceneLocationResolver(file, 1, 10);
```

Create a location occurrence instance:

```
LocationOccurrence LocationOccurrence_instance = new LocationOccurrence("Toronto, Canada",0);
```

Add it to a list and try and resolve the location:

```
List<ResolvedLocation> result = locRes.resolveLocations(locations, false);
```

Am I using CLAVIN in the right way or is it just not up to scratch?

Backgroud: my main applicatoin is in Python but couldn't find anything that would do the job. So i'm using JPype to interact with CLAVIN using Python.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response. CLAVIN would prefer to treat "Toronto, Canada" as two separate locations. So, you should try creating two LocationOccurrence instances:

```
LocationOccurrence LocationOccurrence_A = new LocationOccurrence("Toronto",0);
LocationOccurrence LocationOccurrence_B = new LocationOccurrence("Canada",9);
```

I hope that helps. Good luck!